# on opening filefield(contains mp4 video) url , it denies access to it. but only videos not other types like image

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, cpanel

my get request in django rest framework returns a url which containes a file(mp4 video) but when i open the url it deny access .but only files which have videos not other types like image or any file(my api is deployed on cpanel host) . but why? how can i fix it?)

here is my code:

```
models.py


class Videos(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos', null=True)
```

i created a filefield here and i uploaded a video with mp4 format in django admin

```
serializers.py

class VideosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Videos
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'video')
```

and this is my views:

```
views.py

from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .serializers import VideosSerializer
from .models import Videos


class VideosView(ListAPIView):
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
serializer_class = VideosSerializer
queryset = Videos.objects.all()
```

and in the end  urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('videos', VideosView.as_view(), name='videos')
]
```

when i call the request it gives me the url and it works fine . but when i open the url link
it denies access with a 403 forbbiden error and i didn't use any authentication or user . cause i just want to give the url.i don't need authentcation classes .
as i told before this happens on cpanel host i deployed not on local host.
and also it just happens to video files like mp4 format.it works fine on image or pdf or anything else.

can some one help me fix this?
i guess it's because of the content-type or media-type but i have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys for anyone who's reading this post i've found the problem myself and wanted to share it with you . the problem was the mime types and permissions in cpanel host . you have to set mime types and permissions so the videos could be allowed .